# Database Design Issue - Altering to accommodate new issue

Tags: database, postgresql, schema

Our problem is to design a database system that registers players at a club to play sports and play on teams registered to one sport. A player should be able to play a sport without being assigned to a team. I missed this important point by accident and now I am struggling to re-design my current schema. Is there a simple way to allow this using my current design?

```
create table IF NOT EXISTS sports (
    sport_id SERIAL,
    sport_name VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY(sport_id)
    );

create table IF NOT EXISTS players (
    player_id SERIAL,
    player_name VARCHAR(50),
    player_phone VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY(player_id)
    );

create table IF NOT EXISTS teams (
    team_name VARCHAR(50),
    sport_id int REFERENCES sports(sport_id),
    captain_id INT REFERENCES players(player_id),
    PRIMARY KEY (team_name, sport_id)
    );

create table IF NOT EXISTS has_players (
    team_name VARCHAR(50),
    sport_id int,
    player_id INT REFERENCES players(player_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (team_name, sport_id) 
        REFERENCES teams(team_name, sport_id),
    PRIMARY KEY(team_name, sport_id, player_id)
    );



create table IF NOT EXISTS time_slot (
    training_id SERIAL,
    training_day VARCHAR(9),
    training_time TIME,
    team_name VARCHAR(50),
    sport_id int,
    FOREIGN KEY (team_name, sport_id) 
        REFERENCES teams (team_name, sport_id),
    CONSTRAINT check_day CHECK (training_day ~* '(\W|^)Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|
    Saturday|Sunday(\W|$)'),
    PRIMARY KEY (training_id)
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your model is constructed, there's only a link between teams and sports, no link between players and sports.  You can always add one additional table quite easily, and make it possible to say that a certain player plays a certain sport.

```
create table IF NOT EXISTS players_sports (
    player_id INT REFERENCES players(player_id),
    sport_id int REFERENCES sports(sport_id),
    PRIMARY KEY (player_id, sport_id)
    );
```

Then in teams, you could just adjust this:

```
sport_id int REFERENCES sports(sport_id),
captain_id INT REFERENCES players(player_id),
```

to this:

```
sport_id int REFERENCES players_sports(sport_id),
captain_id INT REFERENCES players_sports(player_id),
```

This accomplishes that all teams have an associated sport, players don't have to be on a team, and you can join to the player captain information, from the team (albeit through one additional table, players_sports)

Comment: Would there be any way to alter this again to prevent a player from joining a team for a sport they don't already play?#

Comment: This model would already support that.  You would need a condition: before a player could be inserted into `has_player` you would check to see if a corresponding record exists in players_sports.  If it doesn't, then you can't insert that record into has_players, because that player doesn't play that sport.

Comment: Using a CONSTRAINT? I've dabbled in constraints before, as you can see above... That doesn't work, either because of the RegEx or the SQL I dunno...